# VS Code: Using Grunt from node_modules\.bin

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, visual-studio-code

I am experimenting with Visual Studio Code, Node.js and Grunt and running into problems. Essentially, I can't seem to convince VS Code to run `grunt` from the local `node_modules\.bin` location where `npm` puts it. Everything works if I install `grunt` and `grunt-cli` globally but, personally, I don't see why I should have to do that.

I have a `package.json` file that looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "VSCODETEST",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {

        "grunt": "~0.4.5",
        "grunt-cli": "~1.1.0",

        "typescript": "~1.8.9",
        "grunt-typescript": "~0.8.0"

    },

    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "~2.2.2",
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.2"
    }
}
```

Running `npm install` downloads the dependency hierarchy.

I have various tasks defined in my `gruntfile.js`, in the root of my project, and this tasks file in `.vscode\tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "grunt",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": []
}
```

I know that's working because, after installing the tools globally with...

```
npm install -g grunt grunt-cli
```

... VS Code does automatically pick up the tasks in the gruntfile and show them to me in the U.I.

However, if I don't install those globally (or I uninstall them, globally), it gives me this error:

```
'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Clearly, it can't find `grunt` in its path so I attempted to remedy that by modifying the tasks file...

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "${workspaceRoot}\\node_modules\\.bin\\grunt",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": []
}
```

This solves the error but I no longer get any tasks listed - I only get "no tasks found"

How can I either include `node_modules\.bin` in the PATH that VS Code uses to find its tools or work around this some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: `.vscode\tasks.json` should look like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "${cwd}/node_modules/.bin/grunt",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "default",
            "args": [],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch"
        }
    ]
}
```

The important change is the specification of the `command` to run.

Additionally, in `gruntfile.js`, it is necessary to actually register tasks that match the `taskName` given to tasks in VS Code's configuration file. For example, the `default` task in my example, above, is registered as follows:

```
// Default Task is to run grunt-ts build task named `ts'
grunt.registerTask("default", ["ts"]);
```